Are these specks by the door trim from termites or pests?
My den door (faces outside) has a small gap under the door trim and I've noticed a gradual accumulation of small specks. I vacuumed this awhile back which is why it's strange that it's back again. No one else is in the house, I have no pets or anything. This is the only part of the house where this shows up. I googled some termite droppings and this didn't look too close to that, but I'm not entirely sure. What's the fix here, do I need to replace the entire trim or would sealing it up be sufficient?


That looks like a number of mixed things. I'd clean it up and see what it is replaced with.

I’d call a professional to come look. Definitely don’t seal it up, it’s droppings from some sort of insect or pest that needs to be exterminated. Whatever it is, it’s eating that door frame.
